# Using and id predefined by an sql model in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise, postgresql-9.3

I'm getting started with Rails and I've been struggling with this.

The problem is that when I try to login the following error came out.(I'm using devise)

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: no existe la columna usuario.id LINE 1: ...b4c1d3674118467080c9d5ae9b1d67353f050b' ORDER BY "usuario".... ^ : SELECT "usuario".* FROM "usuario" WHERE "usuario"."confirmation_token" = '6e4568f260aa4a6524bebb77feb4c1d3674118467080c9d5ae9b1d67353f050b' ORDER BY "usuario"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

The thing is that when I go to the table `usuario` in postgres the primary key or ID is called `usuario_id` and not `id`.

I don't know why rails takes it like only `id`.

If someone can help me how to change this it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the primary key column name using the [`primary_key=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key-3D) setter in your model:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'usuario_id'
end
```

Comment: That worked man!, but now I'm getting the error of PG.

PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: the null value for column «usuario_id» violates the restriction not null.

I undertand that it violates de restriction, how can I autoincrement  the ID without entering it through the sign up form?

Comment: Also, when I go to \d usuario in Postgres I get this for the table usuario.
   COLUMN                    TYPE                          MODIFIERS
 usuario_id             | integer                     | not null